# The while loop used is not doing anything when it is supposed to make m equal to the HCF

Tags: java, class, recursion, while-loop

The program is to find the HCF for m and n,where m is less than n,using a recursive function Hifact(int m,int n).The Hifact part is working but the while loop isn't even though it made sense logically.

```
public class test{
        public static void main(int m,int n)//m<n
        {
            while(m%Hifact(m,n)!=0)//reduces value of m till m%Hifact(m,n)==0
            {
                --m;
            }
            System.out.println(m);
        }
        public static int Hifact(int m,int n)//returns largest number <= m which completely divides n
        {
            if(n%m==0)
            {
                return m;
            }
            else
            {
                return Hifact(m-1,n);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you running this program? Make sure you are passing in the arguments

Comment: when I enter m as 15 and n as 25 in main method, the terminal window is displaying 15 when it should display 5. I am running this program on BlueJ. What I thought was that if m is not divisible by the largest number <= m which completely divides n, m reduces in value till that parameter is met

Comment: shouldn't it be either the loop `while(m%n!=0)` or the recursion `System.out.println(Hifact(m,n));`? And not a combination of both.

Comment: I tried both cases,changing the first one to while(n%m!=0) as n>m, and got the correct answer for some pairs but did not get the right answer for 256 and 1222

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code would work if you instead printed `Hifact(m,n)` on line 8.
I tested this and the code printed 5 as desired. I also tested with some different values that still produced the correct answer.

Comment: Made that change....program works for few pairs of numbers but didn't work for 256 and 1222, whose HCF is 2,displayed 94 as output

Comment: I created a temporary variable temp=m and replaced the m to while(temp%Hifact(m,n)!=0) and now its working.Thanks for all the help